# Installing and compiling Maven artifacts on Java 8

Tags: maven, java-8, maven-compiler-plugin

I have a project with a `pom.xml` that has the following `<build>` declaration:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run `mvn install` on this project, it compiles the project, runs unit tests and publishes it to my local repo. I am trying to learn a little more about Maven here, and am having a tough time finding documentation/explanations on the following:

- How am I able to run `mvn install`, if the POM doesn't declare it under `build/plugins`? Does `maven-compiler-plugin` include `maven-install-plugin`, if so, how could I have figured that out?
- **Most importantly**: the value of `build/plugins/plugin/configuration/source` and `.../target` are both set to `1.8`. If my machine has Java 8 on it, and I run `mvn install` on this project without any errors, does that *guarantee* that the project *builds* with Java 8? I'm looking at the [docs for the Compiler Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) and don't see those `source`/`target` configs listed anywhere.

Comment: For the docs look here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise (+1) - from that link I found the [Lifecycle Doc](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-core/lifecycles.html), and see that `compile` is upstream from `install`, which then explains why doing an `install` triggers a `compile`. However it doesn't explain then why the POM declares the compiler plugin, but not the install plugin. Thoughts?

Comment: @smeeb because it doesn't have to. maven comes bundled with a compile and an install plugin - they are build in. Almost every maven version comes with a different version of these plugins. You _may_ change the version or configure it, but you don't have to. E.g. if you want to tell the compile plugin _how_ (which language level) to compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you should learn what the build life cycle is and how it works and how the plugins [are bound to the life cycle by default](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.5/maven-core/default-bindings.html).

Furthermore you should understand that in Maven every project inherits from the [super pom](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html) file which is part of the maven distribution (the package you have downloaded). The super pom defines the default folder layout and some versions of plugins.

The question to define the maven-compiler-plugin as you did is to be very accurate simply wrong. You should have defined it like the following:

```xml
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

This would overwrite the definition which is inherited by the super pom and changes it's configuration. In your case i would suggest to change the definition into this:

```xml
  <project>
    ...
    <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
      <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    ..
  </project>
```

The encoding should be set globally cause there are other plugins which use this definition like the `maven-resources-plugin`. The usage of the above property simplifies this, cause every plugin which has an option for encoding will use the [default as defined in the property](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#encoding).

To be sure using the correct version of Java (your JDK on your machine) you have to use the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireJavaVersion.html).

Apart from that please take a look onto the [plugins page which shows the most up-to-date releases of the plugins](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/).

As a good documentation i can recomment the [Books on Maven](http://www.sonatype.com/resources/books) but be aware they are written with Maven 2 in mind. So if something is not clear ask on users mailing list of here on SO.

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise (+1) - this is a really great answer, and I will absolutely dig into all those links you posted. Thank you! In the short run, however, I'm still not fully understanding the `1.8` declarations for the compiler plugin. All I want to make sure is that my library compiles and packages (builds) on Java 8. With your suggested changes, would running `mvn install` successfully prove this out? Thanks again!

Comment: You must be a aware that for example a JDK 9 javac compiler has options `source` and `target` as well and can be used to produce Java 1.7 compatible class files. But this can be different from really compiling those classes with an Java 1.7 compiler. The above does the same. If you really need to sure (100%) to use JDK 8 you have to go the way via maven-enforcer-plugin and check the installed JDK to be the version you expect.